# Can I specify a where clause when mapping ids in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model method like this for a model called 'campaign', and each campaign has many outfits:

```
def generate
 ids = self.outfits.map(&:id)
 outfit1 = Outfit.find ids.sample

 begin
  outfit2 = Outfit.find ids.sample
 end while outfit2.id == outfit1.id

 return  [outfit1, outfit2]
end
```

Outfits also have attributes `'scraped'`, and `'status'`. I only wants to map the ids of a campaign's outfits who have the values of `scraped = true`, and `status == 'approved'`.

Comment: what does your code do so far? it looks a bit weird :)..  what does ids.sample mean? do you have a 1:n relation between campain and outfit, and want to get only outfits of a campain which are scraped true and status approved? Is that your question?

Comment: ids.sample will return a random element from the array. is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah, so basically I want the ids array to contain only the ids of outfits who's status is approved and scraped==true. And then I want to sample that array to get the outfit object. The overall goal of this method is two generate two unique outfits that belong the campaign, and then return them. Does that make sense?

Comment: What's the purpose of the randomly selected ids in your code attempt and how does that relate to selecting ids of items with the attributes you want?

Comment: How is that relevant to answering my question? Sorry if that sounded rude, but I don't think that information is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have just tested this in my rails console myself initially,

`self.outfits.where(:scraped => true).where(:status => 'Approved').map(&:id)`

does the trick.

Comment: I can't accept my own answer right away, I need to wait 2 days.

Comment: better use .pluck(:id) instead of map(&:id). its more efficient because it works on the db level, so it doesn't create a instance for each outfit and also dont have to iterate over them just to get the id. just a performance improvement :)

Comment: @Matthias, thanks for the tip! I'm new to this so I really appreciate learning little things that can lead to performance improvement. Writing code that not only works, but also gives optimal performance is what I think separates a good programmer from an average one.